# Cannot use Like statement in Android SQLite with argument and % character

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 1 because the index is out of range.  The statement
>   has 0 parameters.

Android doesn't recognise `?` character in `?%`

I try to achieve this:

```
 String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM config WHERE Directory Like '?%';";

 SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
 Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[] {parent});
```

I have searched for a solution but couldn't find anything, I think it's pretty particullary. I am trying to do it like this because I want to make the query work with `Strings` that contains character `'`.

Maybe someone who had the same problem can answer me how can I solve this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `||` to concat parameter and wildcard:

```
SELECT * FROM config WHERE Directory Like ? || '%';
```

Comment: Still doesn't work :( same error "SELECT * FROM config WHERE Directory Like '?' || '%';"

Comment: @PavelMarian Try without `'` around ?

Comment: Work's like a charm, going to accept the answer after the time limit. Didn't know I could concatenate the strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM config WHERE Directory Like '?' || '%';

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[] {parent});
```

using `||` solves this issue

Answer (score -2):

you can put what condition you have into a `String` variable and then pass it to your query like this--> `String Condition="'?";
SELECT * FROM config WHERE Directory Like '"+Condition+"'`

Comment: And allow SQL Injection attack

Comment: @lad2025: there are many ways that you can block SQL Injection attack.

Comment: The first rule is: **Avoid building custom string, use parameter binding instead**

Comment: @lad2025: sometimes you need to do your work in another way. but this do not mean you are mistake. just you are some flexible.

Comment: Good joke exposing to SQL attack Injection for being flexible.

Comment: @lad2015: flexible for the end.

Comment: using this code is not mean you are in attack in every minutes. may be is illegal with sql injection rules. but we can not say if you use this code then you must ready for attacking. i think this can be joke.

Comment: @karimkhan "there are many ways that you can block SQL Injection attack" - yes there are, and the best one is to use parameter binding.  All it takes is for either you or the person working on the code after you to forget to filter the input correctly and you have inadvertently created a massive security hole.